# Limping צלע and פסח

Tags: words, hebrew, medicine, vayishlach, parashas-emor

צלע (Genesis/[Bereshit 32:32](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0132.htm#32))

> וַיִּֽזְרַֽח־ל֣וֹ הַשֶּׁ֔מֶשׁ כַּאֲשֶׁ֥ר עָבַ֖ר אֶת־פְּנוּאֵ֑ל וְה֥וּא **צֹלֵ֖עַ** עַל־יְרֵכֽוֹ׃
>
> And the sun rose upon him as he passed over Peniel, and he **limped** upon his thigh.

and פסח (Leviticus/[Vayikra 21:18](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0321.htm#18) for example)

> כִּ֥י כׇל־אִ֛ישׁ אֲשֶׁר־בּ֥וֹ מ֖וּם לֹ֣א יִקְרָ֑ב אִ֤ישׁ עִוֵּר֙ א֣וֹ **פִסֵּ֔חַ** א֥וֹ חָרֻ֖ם א֥וֹ שָׂרֽוּעַ׃
>
> For whatsoever man he be that hath a blemish, he shall not approach: a blind man, or a **lame,** or he that hath any thing maimed, or anything too long,

How are both of these words related to limping or to be lame? And what is the difference?

Comment: perhaps, a man walks with 2 legs and an animal with 4, so a different word is not so surprising . for an animal piseach = defectuous 4 walking, tsolea = defectyous 2 walking

Comment: The word פסח is related to being lame and to jumping. I suggest taking a look at the last paragraph of this article: https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/pesach-jumping-for-passover-part-2-2/

Comment: @RebChaimHaQoton the main focus was the difference between them, but thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

Rav Hirsch (Shemos 12:11) explains 'פסח is a limp, stepping haltingly over something', while writing (Tehillim 35:15) צלע means 'to limp, not actually falling but the reeling which precedes an impending fall'.

Both words are connected in the way someone moves in a 'limping' manner, but they are different in *why* the person is limping. Pesach is generally purposeful limping (moving awkwardly over a Jewish house then an Egyptian house) while צלע is involuntary limping before falling.

In the pesukim you mention, perhaps one understanding is that until Yaakov Avinu was healed, he was on the verge of falling. (He *did* use a staff) On the other hand, פסח refers to someone who also was born with such a disability. More than צלע where someone else may have used freewill to damage your means of mobility, perhaps פסח is Hashem purposefully creating someone with this disability from birth to accomplish their life mission.

Another thought: the [Malbim (Emor 47)](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.21.18?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Malbim_on_Leviticus%2C_Emor.47.1&lang2=bi) writes "או פסח: שם "פסח" כולל בין ברגלו אחת בין בשתי רגליו אחר שמצאנו (שמואל ב ט יג) "והוא פסח בשתי רגליו" וזה ההבדל בין פסח ובין צולע. שהצולע הוא על ידי שנשמט הירך והולך על צלע אחת. והפסח דולג"

Comment: +1, although just to add: a פסח can also be someone who wasn't born that way but became so later (Mefiboshes is described פסח שתי רגליו, and he was injured in an accident when he was five years old).

Comment: @Meir Interesting! Perhaps Mefiboshes can also be described as someone purposefully 'created' to have the disability since he lost his mobility as a young child